# Add trailing slash for specific rewritten query

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on an "ManualTranslation" class and I am stuck at .htaccess part.

I am trying to rewrite this query `?language=xx` into `/xx/` only.

So far I manage to make it work, not sure if it's any good or proper... But it is missing one thing for sure. If for some reason – someone try to select language manually by saying:

`http://domain.com/it` and forgets to add trailing slash, my .htaccess pieces fails. So it should add automatically that trailing slash if it's missing from this query parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [QSA]
```

So for now, this only works this way:
`http://domain.com/it/` but not `http://domain.com/it` because of missing trailing slash which should be there.

If anyone can tell me what am I missing?

---

Also I am wondering if there is a chance to remove that rewritten query string with `php` if it fails to find the language. Right now I am just basically redirecting back to current file and I am not satisfied with it...

```
if ( isset($query) && !$this->isAllowed($query) )
{
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your current rule to allow URLs not ending with `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.*?[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})(/.*)?$ $2?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However keep in mind that a URL like `http://domain.com/contacts` will remain unaffected with above rule and you won't have `language` parameter populated.

Comment: Yes, yes. I am aware that language parameter will be gone on each page redirect. But I am storing "selected/detected" language into session for later use. I assume I could use PHP to force language parameter, but I don't mind it this way. 

Your rewrite does work now with "/" and without it, but that's probably not good for SEO? I think it should only work as "/xx/" always closed. Can it force trailing slash when missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond ^([a-z]{2})$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Put it just after your `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: Internal Server Error 500